# `require': libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/path/vendor/local/libxml-ruby-2.4.0/lib/libxml_ruby.so

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-upgrade

we are trying to upgrade ruby version of our rails application, currently, it's running in ruby 1.8.7 as a initial step trying to upgrade 1.9.2

when we trying to run ./bundle exec rails s we are getting below error

`` vendor/local/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require': libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/sakthi/Sakthi/trunk_upgrade_v1/vendor/local/libxml-ruby-2.4.0/lib/libxml_ruby.so ``

but I can see llibxml_ruby.so file that path

Comment: This is probably not very helpful but that path looks wrong to me what happems if you type `ls /home/sakthi/Sakthi/trunk_upgrade_v1/vendor/local/libxml-ruby-2.4.0/lib` I think you may find you have a path problem. It's not a solution though sorry

Comment: If type above mentioned command it list `libxml  libxml.rb  libxml_ruby.so xml  xml.rb` files and folders